# Get data from mongodb (mongoose) to jade view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

I'm stuck trying to get mongodb data in my jade views. I'm a newbie with node.js and I apologize if this seems stupid!
I can see what's in my table in the console:

```
Material.find(function (err, materials){
  console.log(materials);
});
```

But I want to pass that data to my jade view

```
app.get('/help', function(req, res){
  res.render('help', {materials: materials});
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track! Just put the rendering in the callback from the `find`:

```
app.get('/help', function(req, res){
  Material.find(function (err, materials){
    res.render('help', {materials: materials});
  });
});
```

Comment: cool! thanks Brandon..but how can I show the results in my jade view?